# How to Configure WAMP Server so that Multi developer can work on common Server on Network

Tags: wampserver

I am installing WAMP Server on Windows 7 (Local Server) E: drive and this drive is shared with developers. 
We have 5-10 developers team working on a project. So how to configure my server so that developers can use common Server.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can access by its ip address eg:-  //192.168.1.1/project folder name

Comment: Thanks, but my Wamp Server is not working on Server E: drive, i have done changes in windows host file and used new port no 82 for wamp server

Comment: If you want it to run on the server, then you have to install it on the server, not on a drive mapped to the server on your PC

Comment: This is not the way to do it anyway. Install it on each developers PC and get a source management tool like GIT so you can share the source